# What is the best approach to use Controller, Facade, Service, Repository in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, service, controller, facade

I wanna to know the best approach to use Controller, Facade, Service, Repository in Spring MVC.

The structure in my current project is:

```
AController -> AService(business logic in here) -> ARepository

BController -> BService(business logic in here) -> BRepository
```

and other CDE... Controller, Service, Repository

But when business logic get complicated, I don't know which design is correct:

```
1. AController -> AService & BService & ...CDE Service

2. AController -> AService -> BCD Service

3. AController -> AFacade -> ABCD... Service
```

And if I choose the answer 3, can I still use its own Service as below?

```
AController -> AFacade -> ABCD... Service

AController -> AService
```

Or I can't invoke the AService from AController anymore but invoke by AFacade only?

Thanks for answer.